# Prevent window from opening twice…

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I execute these lines to show the preferences window:

```
-(IBAction)showPreferences:(id)sender {
    PreferencesWindowController *preferencesWindowController = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] init];
    NSNib *preferencesNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"PreferencesWindow" bundle:nil];
    [preferencesNib instantiateNibWithOwner:preferencesWindowController topLevelObjects:nil];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [[preferencesWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]; 
    [preferencesNib release];
}
```

But when the user clicks a second time on the preferences button (and the preferences window is still open) it will open up another instance of the preferences window.

How should I prevent this without hacking around with control variables? Should I edit my PreferencesWindowController to be a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to make a PreferencesWindowController ivar in whatever class this action belongs to:

```
@interface foo : NSObject
{
@private
  PreferencesWindowController *_pwc;
}
- (IBAction) showPreferencesWindow:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation foo

- (void) dealloc
{
  [_pwc release], _pwc = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) showPreferencesWindow:(id)sender
{
  if(nil == _pwc)
    _pwc = [[PreferencesWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferencesWindow"];
  [_pwc showWindow:sender];
}

@end
```

Comment: Well, that's what I meant with "hacking around with control variables". Isn't there an elegant way to eg. initialize the window?

Comment: Anyway, if I do it like this, when I close the preferences window, it will never open again, because _pwc is not nil.

Comment: Why do you consider having ivars a hack?  What do you consider inelegant about this approach?

Comment: Because I thought Apple could have a way of creating a "special window" which is opened only once. But it's OK ;-) Could you give me a hint how I set _pwc to nil when the preferences window closes?

Comment: _pwc controller owns the window.  It only has to be allocated once and can show and hide the window as many times as necessary.  I recommend reviewing http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake while typing the "if-block". Thanks, it works fine, as you said!